# Vintage Photo Printing

Tags: printing, color, vintage

I have some old color (C-prints?) photographs that were printed in the 80's which are quite faded. I would like to have them reprinted but would like to have them printed on the same paper as they were originaally. Are there  any labs that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have them reprinted but would like to have them printed on the same paper as they were originaally. Are there any labs that will do this?

You'd have to confirm that the original paper is still in production -- it might not be. But as long as it is, any lab that's willing to do custom work should be able to do it for you. Googling ***darkroom services*** turned up a number of custom photo labs that do this kind of thing.